Finding an example of a set that is NOT a metric space, IS sequentially compact, IS limit point compact, and is NOT compact
Can someone help me find an example of a set that has the following characteristics?

It is NOT a metric space
It IS sequentially compact
It IS limit point compact, i.e., weakly countably compact
It is NOT compact.

Thank you.
Barnaby Finch

Pi-base has a tool for searching examples of spaces by property. This is what it does for $(2)\land (3)\land (4)$: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%7Ecompact+%2B+Sequentially+Compact+%2BWeakly+Countably+Compact Notice that $((2)\land (4))\Rightarrow (1)$. I advise you to always check on your own because sometimes there are mistakes.

We'd be quite happy if community members reported such mistakes via https://github.com/pi-base/data/issues

https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Sequentially+Compact%2BWeakly+Countably+Compact%2B%7EMetrizable%2B%7ECompact provides at least four examples.
The ordinal $\omega_1$ is the classic example. It's not compact by considering the cover by $[0,\alpha)$ for each $\alpha<\omega_1$.
This space is sequentially compact since every sequence has a limit point at its supremum. Therefore the space is also weakly countably compact, since every sequentially compact space is countably compact and thus weakly countably compact.
As pointed out in the comments, if one is familiar with the result that compactness and sequential compactness coincide for metrizable spaces, then we must conclude this space is not metrizable.

Not so subtle. In a metric space, compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness. ‍♂️‍♂️

This is true, assuming you believe all of the following. https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Metrizable%2BCompact%2B%7ESequentially+Compact https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Metrizable%2B%7ECompact%2BSequentially+Compact

What I said is a routine theorem proved in every point set topology course and book.

I don't disagree, but I was limiting my answer to what could be shown more or less directly from the definitions.
